# Complex data collection with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm delving into Entity Framework for the first time - using Visual Studio 2010, as I'm not currently in a position to upgrade, which I think makes it V4.

One concept I'm having trouble working out is how to handle complex calculated values that need to be worked out from the database.

As a very simple example, if I have two entities: one being the parent and one being the child - is it possible to get an instance of the parent and then get a value calculated from the number of child entities without having to load the child entities?

Normally I would create get/update/delete store procedures in the database, and in the get I would have a `(Select Count(*) From Child Where ChildId = ParentId) As NumChildren` and store that value against the parent.

(This is a very simple example, and what I want to do is massively more complex, involving multiple tiers and specific properties.  Therefore I don't want to have to load every single entity just to get the counts)

But how do you do that in Entity Framework?

Comment: Count(1) being a very simple example doesn't add any performance impact. But I am sure your complex logic has some performance impact. The best can be to create a DB View at your database side, and map a entity to that. What u think?

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav - if I understand you correctly, you're saying that I'd have to manually create a view in the database, replicating all the individual columns from the `Parent` table (in my example), and then create a new entity in the framework for this view?  So in this case you'd have 3 entities, the `Parent` the `Child` and the `ParentView`?  Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: It might not look cleaner, but that will give u better performance. Yes "ParentView"